# JMeter - Convert Unicode Hex Char to "normal string"

Tags: jmeter

I automating a script in which I am using a regular expression to extract the path of the next HTTP request, the problem is that the value matched with the regular expression contains things like `&#x2f;`, so I need to convert that into`/`, in order to be able to send the path in a valid format.
I expect that it should be possible to do that using a PostProcessor, but I am not sure of how it should be scripted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are the proper HTML/XML-encoded characters, you can use inline function [__unescapeHtml](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__unescapeHtml), e.g.:

```
${__unescapeHtml(&#x2f;)}
```

The function above uses Apache's [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) under the hood, so you can call it from BeanShell post-processor:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

vars.put("myvar", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#x2f;"));
```

The same library has a bunch of other functions, that may be useful, depending on what you are decoding from, for example:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

vars.put("myvarxml", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml("&#x2f;"));
```